# How to run service on every table update

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to implement a way to run a specific service in Entity Framework Core when data is added/deleted in a specific azure sql server's table. In general, I'm wondering how this is implemented if the execution is done on updates to a specific table.

I want it to work at the same time as the DB trigger is firing. I need to send a message to the servicebus after all the data has been applied to the actual database

Comment: Could you please give more explanation?

Comment: You can use triggers to know when the value is updated/added or deleted. Based on that response yiu can run your service

Comment: @Mohanraj Periyannan 
yes. i want send message to azure service bus, when specific database table has updated

Comment: Which database are you using? For example, see [Query Notifications in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/query-notifications-in-sql-server)

Comment: @Alexander Petrov
i'm using azure sql server now :)
I'm thinking of using an interceptor, but, 
I want it to work at the same time as the DB trigger is firing.
I need to send a message to the servicebus after all the data has been applied to the actual database.

maybe... A DB broker might help

Comment: Don't write in the comments. Edit the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this approach, create a custom repository class (YourEntityRepository) that depends on your YourDbContext. Within the repository class, you define methods for adding and deleting entities, where you can execute your specific service methods (YourSpecificService) accordingly. The SaveChanges method can be used to persist the changes to the database.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).